# wp get attachment image always gives me thumbnail

Tags: images, attachments

I have an image which should be output on the page. The space is limited (width-max = 209px). Now I have to provide the image in a scaled size, if the user doesn't do it.

This is my code:

```
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($logo, 'full');
$width = $src[1];
$height = $src[2];
$new_width = 200;
$factor = $width/$new_width;
$new_height = round($height/$factor);
echo wp_get_attachment_image($logo, array($new_width, $new_height))
```

But the image used is the thumbnail image (150x150) and the width and height in the html code is 92!

```
<img width="92" height="92" title="my title" alt="Logo" class="attachment-200x92" src="http://www.test.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/logo-150x150.jpg">
```

In the docu it is stated that I should use `add image size` but the height can be different for each picture. Also what happens with already uploaded pictures?

How can I fix this?

**Solution:**

`add_image_size( 'squeeze', 200, 1000, false );` and Regenerate Thumbnails did the job for me.

Comment: What was the *original* size of the uploaded image?

Comment: 2677 (width) x 1232 (height)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real workhorses behind `wp_get_attachment_image_src` are [`image_downsize`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/image_downsize) & [`image_get_intermediate_size`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/image_get_intermediate_size).

Between the two, they'll attempt to find the largest image available **that fits within the constraints of the required size**.

The return value of `wp_get_attachment_image_src` will be:

```
Array(
    [0] => 'source of image that best fits',
    [1] => 'width of source image'
    [2] => 'height of source image',
)
```

> Also what happens with already uploaded pictures?

Nothing. You'll need a plugin like [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) if you've changed your media settings/added image sizes, and want to apply them to all exisiting images.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. `image_downsize` gives me always thumb. `image_get_intermediate_size` also gave me a thumb (150x150). Also I don't know the exact height/width. I can only calculate the height. I want the following: 1) Extract the orginal width/height ->Done. 2) Calculate a matching height (width is set to a constant) -> Done. 3) Get a scaled image with the new width/height -> Problems

Comment: `wp_get_attachment_image` won't give you a *scaled* image, it'll give an image that best fits. Since you're asking for an image no wider than `200`, the thumb is the only candidate.

Comment: So taking the original image size (2677 x 1232) and scaling it down with HTML is the only option for me?

Comment: Well, you could grab the `medium` & scale it, or register a new image size & regenerate the existing ones with Regenerate Thumbnails.

Comment: If the original image size is e.g. 320x115 would than `mendium` work? Registering a new image size is difficult, because the sizes could be completely different in height. There is no fixed size. But I'll say the user that he should upload not to use big images.

Comment: Just use something like `add_image_size( 'squeeze', 200, 1000, false )`. This'll create a *scaled* image (because `crop` is false) no wider than 200, and no taller than 1000. Unless you upload a ridiculously exaggerated portrait image, `scaled` will always be 200px wide.

Comment: Does it then have a height of 1000px everytime? If no than it would work, but I have to use Regenerate Thumbnails.

Comment: No, because the `false` means it's *scaled*, not cropped. As I said before, unless we're talking a super tall image to start with, setting a large height will force WP to downscale against the width, so you'll end up with proportional images of width 200.